# StructType can not accept object float in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, tuples

Why this is working just fine

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
l=[("foo",83.33)]
schema = StructType([
   StructField("type", StringType(), True),
   StructField("value", DoubleType(), True)])
df= spark.createDataFrame(l,schema)
```

And this

```
 l=[(83.33)]
    schema = StructType([
    StructField("value", DoubleType(), True)])
    df= spark.createDataFrame(l,schema)
```

Gives me an error

```
StructType can not accept object 83.33 in type <class 'float'>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using a one element tuple, a trailing comma is required. Check this [TupleSyntax](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax)

```
>>> l=[(83.33,)]           //note the comma (,)
>>> schema = StructType([
...     StructField("value", DoubleType(), True)])
>>> df= spark.createDataFrame(l,schema)
>>> df.show()
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|83.33|
+-----+
```

Comment: @Yakov: Updated with explanation and a link

Comment: python never fails surprising me